# How to define density of subset in countable discrete group

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

We know that for a susbet A of integers $\mathbb{Z}$, the upper density $d(A)$ of $A$ can be defined by
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2n+1}|A\cap [-2n,2n]|.$$
More general, if $G$ is a countable discrete amenable group, and $F=\{F_n\}$ is a Folner sequence in $G$, the upper density of $A\subset G$ can be defined by
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{|F_n|}|A\cap F_n|.$$
Similarly, we can define the lower density.

However, in a countable discrete group, we may not take these special sequences. So my question is whether there is a similar definition of density of the subset in countable discrete groups.

Comment: I imagine the definition depends on a choice of independent generators - you can then use balls in the Cayley graph.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Because I am unfamilar to the definitions you said, could you add some details or references?